# how to prepare static format

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdictionary

i am new to ios i want prepare static format for dictionarys and keys

```
{
"bible": {
    "book": [
        {
            "bookName": "Genesis",
            "chapter": [
                {
                    "chapterNum": "1",
                    "verse": [
                        {
                            "verse": "In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.",
                            "verseNum": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "verse": "And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.",
                            "verseNum": "2"
                        },
```

Comment: Are you looking for plists? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html

Comment: So what's your problem bro?

Comment: i want to prepare static data in the above format

Comment: Can you throw some light on what exactly you want to ask?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"bible": {
    "book": [
        {
            "bookName": "Genesis",
            "chapter": [
                {
                    "chapterNum": "1",
                    "verse": [
                        {
                            "verse": "In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.",
                            "verseNum": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "verse": "And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.",
                            "verseNum": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

The same you can check at jsonlint.com

Anything else?

Comment: thank you but i am assking how to prepare this format

Comment: like if i want to prepare dictionary: nsdictionary *dict = @{"bible":@{"book":@[@{